# Not the output i want in nested while loop

Tags: java

My case is to write a nested while loop in Java to produce the following output.So the 1
12
123 has to come. Not the other way around and I can't fix it. (First introduction to while loops in Java)

Testing something 1

Testing something 1
Testing something 2

Testing something 1
Testing something 2
Testing something 3

Testing something 1
Testing something 2
Testing something 3
Testing something 4

And so forth.

Here is my code

```
public static void testingWhileLoops(int amount) {
    int i = 1;
    while (i <= 7) {
        int k = i;
        while (k >= 1) {
            System.out.println(k + "Testing something");
            k--;
        }
        System.out.println();
        i++;
    }
}
```

```
1Testing something

2Testing something
1Testing something

3Testing something
2Testing something
1Testing something

4Testing something
3Testing something
2Testing something
1Testing something
```

Comment: Re-read the section about loops in the book/tutorial you're using. It talks about `for` which is a more natural way to handle such things.

Comment: If you insist on using `while`, try with `k = 1`, `while (k <= i)`, and `k++`.

Comment: What is your expected output ?

Comment: Use `print` in the inner loop, not `println`. Add the variable at the end of the print, not the beginning. Use a loop that counts up, not down.

Comment: You should use `System.out.print` inside your inner `while` loop. [link to docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#print(java.lang.String))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If you want the number after the text, you may print it after

   ```
   System.out.println("Testing something " + k + " ");
   ```
2. If you don't want to go to a new line use `print` instead of `println`

   ```
   System.out.print("Testing something " + k + " ");
   ```
3. If you want the value to increase, start it at `1` and use `k++`, and use the `amount` value in your code for the outer loop

   ```
   static void testingWhileLoops(int amount) {
       int i = 1;
       while (i <= amount) {
           int k = 1;
           while (k <= i) {
               System.out.print("Testing something " + k + " ");
               k++;
           }
           System.out.println();
           i++;
       }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an approach for you:

```
public static void testingWhileLoops(int amount) {
    int i = 1;
    //This flag will control the vertical number of levels
    while(i <= amount) {
        int k = 1;
        //This flag will control the horizontal number of prints
        while(k <= i) {
            System.out.print("Testing something " + k + " ");
            k++;
        }
        i++;
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Testing something 1 
Testing something 1 Testing something 2 
Testing something 1 Testing something 2 Testing something 3 
Testing something 1 Testing something 2 Testing something 3 Testing something 4 
Testing something 1 Testing something 2 Testing something 3 Testing something 4 Testing something 5
```

Comment: since you initialize `i` and `k` wiith 0, the conditions for the while loops should be made with `<` instead of `<=`. Or initialize `i` and `k`with 1. With your current solution always 1 line and column more will be printed than what was requested by `amount`.  if you execute `testingWhileLoops(7)` 8 lines and 8 columns will be printed.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to change the condition of the loop.
also, change to use unused variables 'amount'.
See my code below.

```java
public class StackOverflowTest {
    public static void testingWhileLoops(int amount) {
        int i = 1;
        while (i <= amount) {
            int k = 1;
            while (k <= i) {
                System.out.print("Testing something " + k + " ");
                k++;
            }
            System.out.println();
            i++;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        testingWhileLoops(4);
    }
}
```

#### Output:

```
Testing something 1 
Testing something 1 Testing something 2 
Testing something 1 Testing something 2 Testing something 3 
Testing something 1 Testing something 2 Testing something 3 Testing something 4
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```java
public class TestwhileLoops {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        testingWhileLoops(7);
    }

    public static void testingWhileLoops(int amount) {

        int row = 1;
        while (row <= amount) {
            int col = 1;
            while (col <= row) {
                System.out.print("Testing something "+col+"  ");
                col++;
            }
            System.out.println();
            row++;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your expected output is as follows:

```
//Testing something 1

//Testing something 1 Testing something 2

//Testing something 1 Testing something 2 Testing something 3

//Testing something 1 Testing something 2 Testing something 3 Testing something 4
```

Use the following code within `testingWhileLoops(amount)`:

```
// Iterate through each row. We set the conditional statement to amount + 1 to
// account for the amount of rows requested.

for(int i = 0; i < amount + 1; i++) {

  for(int j = 0; j < i; j++) {

    System.out.print("Testing Something " + (j+1) + " ");

  }

  System.out.println();

}
```

When `amount` is equal to 4, the desired output will be present.